# Would the question about physics books recommendation for younger kids be on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

I'm looking for a book that would be appropriate for advanced elementary school aged kids describing basics of physics (for those fluent in Russian, an English equivalent of the book "почему вода мокрая").

I'm not quite sure where to ask this - Literature.SE seems a bit far away expertise wise, and Physics SE may consider it off-topic. Thus this question.

Answer (score 2):

Within some limits of being well-specified we've been allowing these.

See the [examples in our tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) [books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) and the meta-question [What are the meanings of “books” and “reference-request”?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/786/520).

Comment: Nah, "books" is still alive and kicking (for now, anyway), with the definition listed in that post you linked to.

Comment: Then my answer is wrong....duur...will edit. Done.

Comment: I should mention, though, that lately I've been thinking the information in book recommendation questions should be transferred to the tag wikis. If and when that happens, there will be no more [tag:books] tag.