# Should we rename the books and reference-request tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, resource-recommendation

Now that our [new recommendation policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed) is in effect, I would like to propose a change that I think will alleviate some misuse of the associated tags:

- [books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) → [resource-recommendation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation)
- [reference-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) → [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference)

I think this better captures the [intended meaning of the tags](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/786/what-are-the-meanings-of-books-and-reference-request).

Thoughts? Better suggestions?

Comment: +1 for both of these.  I used reference-request wrong because I didn't realize it was for a specific reference and I think "books" is too narrow when there are a lot of non-book resources.

Comment: To be clear, if one starts typing "books" or "reference", the system will automatically suggest the new tags, right? Because there is a strong instinct to try tags with 'reference' in particular.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yes, when there is a synonym the suggestions system still works. It also puts an "also books" at the bottom of the tag. (And if you type in the old tag anyway, it gets converted). Try it out with the qft tag if you want, it is synonymed to the fullform.

Comment: I'll wait another day or so and then make this change if nobody objects in that time.

Comment: The two new synonyms are now in function.

Comment: Should this also apply to the meta tag [meta-tag:books]?

Comment: Observation 01.01.2014: The new tag-name 'resource-recommendations' might be mistakenly interpreted as an invitation to ask for book-reviews of specific books, which is usually off-topic. See e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91888/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the current synonyms have been changed from the proposal; since July 2014, **both** [books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) and [reference-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) map to [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations). This is intended to catch a large number of users who were using the `reference-request` tag when the post is best described by the `resource-recommendations` flavour.

The `specific-reference` flavour, on the other hand, is rarer, and can be re-tagged by hand if needed. So if you see something that should have the [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference) tag and doesn't yet, add it in.